# Expression does not evaluate to column or table name?

Tags: mapbasic

This is my code:

```
Include "MAPBASIC.DEF"
Include   "MENU.DEF"

Dim s_filename As String
s_filename = FileOpenDlg("","","TAB"," Open Table Interactive") 
Browse * From s_filename
```

I want to open a file from my computer.

Comment: Could you provide additional details about what it is you want to do, or any errors associated with it? Your title and question within the body don't match

Answer (score 1):

First, you must open a table. **FileOpenDlg()** function only get full path as a string.

Second, your Browse statement is not correct, because you are putting a full path instead of a simple table name (you could extract it with **PathToTableName$()** function).

```
Dim s_FileName, s_TableName As String

s_FileName = FileOpenDlg("","","TAB"," Open Table Interactive") 
s_TableName = PathToTableName$(s_FileName)

Open Table s_FileName as s_TableName Interactive
Browse * From s_TableName
```

Or last two could be also

```
Open Table s_FileName    
Browse * From s_TableName
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an Alias variable to hold a table name only. It's intended to point at a combination of a table and column name, like: sTableName + ".ID". So I would suggest that you change the dim to: Dim sTableName As String